# How to see release notes *before* updating?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I look at release notes *before* updating visual studio code? I saw an update was available in the gear icon in lower left, clicked it, only saw the 'Install update...', the '...' made me think that there would be a further dialog with options, but there wasn't. And now it is already updated (or will be when I restart).

Isn't there an easy way to see the release notes (inside vs code, not by searching the web), *before* doing the update?

Comment: go to the site https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23 and not possible in the app without updating

Comment: Thanks @SurajRao. So I did this:
1. See in gear icon in lower left corner that there is an update available.
2. Click the gear icon. There is an option 'Install Update...'. Despite the '...' I now know from experience that there will be no further dialog..it will just go ahead and install the update. 
3. Go to the link you provided. I see this: 'Update 1.23.1: The update addresses these issues.' The word 'Issues' is a link. I click that.
4. Aaand...nothing. No way to see what new changes or fixes I will bring into my VS Code installation if I update.

Comment: So, apparently, when there's an update, if you wait a while, you will get a popup in the lower *right* corner that says 'update available' and that one *does* have the option to view the release notes before updating. But unfortunately there's no way to bring up that better, more functional popup, on demand. If you click it then close it theres no way to get back to it other than searching the web. Weird design. It should be in the 'Install updates..' in the lower left, accessible at any time.